# MySQL sorting multiple columns with different sort order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table in which I have three fields with data type `date`, `int` and `bigint`.

I want to sort my select query using all these three columns. I want to sort them all in descending order. For example:

```
Select * From mytbl 
order by date desc,intnum desc, bigintnum desc;
```

Is it possible that i could get a result starting from max of all three columns.
like latest date, highest intnum and higest bigintnum.

Comment: The query you provided looks valid. PS: mysql dba asking sql basics question looks funny ;-)

Comment: @Devjosh: so what? It **is possible** to get the resultset ordered by all fields descendant, started with the highest each column value.

Comment: @zerkms, MySQL DBA:yes it's possible :), Nothing wrong with the query our peer posted in question

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your comments but what I want this query to do is something like this:- I have a data for ex:- 
DATE intnum bigintnum 
2011-07-18 9 546545
2011-07-16 10 123456

Answer (score 2):

no

What your query does is get the `max date`, followed by the `max intnum` of the `max date` followed by the `max bigintnum` of the `max intnum` of the `max date`

In other words, your query would not return the maximum value of all three columns

It orders by the date first, then the intnum, then the bigintnum
The results would be something like this

```
2011-07-20    12    14
2011-07-20    12    13
2011-07-20    11    16
2011-07-20    10    12
2011-07-19    20    15
2011-07-18    60    30
2011-07-18    50    14
```

Comment: you just misunderstood my answer or you're just confused

Comment: @bash :- Yes you are right thats the common behaviour of order by clause but I would want it the way i said ..... any idea using any other way i can do it??? thanks

Comment: @MySQLDBA I don't quite understand what you want to do. Are you trying to get 3 columns where the sort is in DESC order with no relation to the other columns?
Such as this in relation to the one in my answer?

`2011-07-20    60    30`
`2011-07-20    50    16`
`2011-07-20    20    15`

so basically ordering them all separately?

Comment: @MySQLDBA Why don't you update your question and type out what you are trying to output.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get a result starting from max of all three columns. like latest date, highest intnum and higest bigintnum.

```
 Select * From mytbl 
 order by date desc,intnum desc, bigintnum desc;
```

As you know what ORDER BY does, if you have multiple columns in order by clause, It will first order by DATE Desc then for the very first Date it will order by INTNUM Desc and then order by BIGINTNUM.