# User Wall PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a big project a social networking site but now I'm stuck and i need your advice.

My problem is that I wan't to display everything like posts, videos and statuses into his profile.php under user timeline.

I got more than 40 Tables but let me specify what I wan't, I wan't to get data from these tables and how to display them on the profile.php timeline section ?

```
Status Table
------------------------------------------
ID   |    sMessage    |    sDate   |  uId
------------------------------------------
1    | Testing status | 2013/07/03 |   1 


Videos Table
-----------------------------------------------------
ID   |      vName     |   vCode  |    vDate   |  uId
-----------------------------------------------------
1    | PHP and MYSQL  |  2MvYwz  | 2013/07/03 |   1 


Users Table
-----------------------------------
ID   |     uName      |  JoinDate   
-----------------------------------
1    |   Tem Henov    | 2013/07/03
```

And here is what i tried:

```
class userTimeline {
    public function loadTimeline(){
     dbConn();
     $query = "SELECT 
                 sMessage, sDate, vName, vDate, vCode 
               FROM status
               INNER JOIN users
                 ON (status.uId = users.uId)
               INNER JOIN videos
                 On (videos.uId = users.uId)
               WHERE users.uId = '1'";

     return $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

and its loads the data fine but how to display that data in blocks like if its a status display in a separate block and if its a video display it in another block and how to order by date ?! any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> **First :** To Show data into various `<div>` first fetch them and show like,

1) Fetch all the record and store into a php array

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(YOUR_QUERY))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

2) Now Using `foreach()` loop use data fetched from query where ever you want

```
if(is_array($rows)) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        //do with $row or create some if,switch condition here !
    }
}
```

For specific limits and tweaks study the result set we get from `mysql_fetch_array()` !

> **Second :** To short data by date you can use multiple sorting ([click here for
>   tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757334/mysql-sorting-multiple-columns-with-different-sort-order)) but i think you should use [MYSQL UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to merge two
>   or more MySQL query results to get individual sorting result.