# Sort by price and discountPrice

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
product_id | price | discountPrice
    1      |  15   | 12
    2      |  13   | 0
    3      |  20   | 6
```

I want to sort result by discount Price, but if some product_id have a discountPrice equal to 0, this product_id should be sort by price.

Expected result:

```
product_id | price | discountPrice
    3      |  20   | 6
    1      |  15   | 12
    2      |  13   | 0
```

Comment: I believe you have an issue with your model: either discountPrice represents the discount, or the price after discount; maybe you should set the discountPrice to the full price when an item is not discounted.

Answer (score 1):

> I  want to sort result by discount Price, but if some product_id have a discountPrice equal to 0, this product_id should be sort by price.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY CASE WHEN `discountPrice` = 0 THEN `price` ELSE `discountprice` END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

simple you use,
SELECT * FROM yourtable
ORDER BY `discountPrice` DESC, `price` DESC

Comment: This does not sort by `price` when `discountPrice` is equal to 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757334/mysql-sorting-multiple-columns-with-different-sort-order

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this...

```
select *
from yourtable
order by if(discountPrice=0,price,discountPrice) descending;
```

In this case the products come out in order of the lowest available price. Instead of grouping all of the products with no discount at the lowest end of the sorted list. They appear near products with similar prices.